# could someone help me with this particular detail in this article?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves

I'm reading this [article](http://libgen.org/scimag/get.php?doi=10.1007%2Fbf02568416) and I was stuck in this part:

[image]

I didn't understand his trick computing the orders at $P$.

**Remark**: He defines $D=\inf\{div(\omega_{g-1}),div(\omega_g)\}$, i.e., $D=(l_{g-1}-1)P+E$, where $E$ is an effective divisor.

Thanks in advance!